# Is it possible to animate the guide layer itself in Adobe Animate?

Tags: adobe-flash, adobe-animate

I am looking to have a series of objects animate around the perimeter of a blob-like shape. To further illustrate what I'm hoping to achieve, I'd like to have the hairs of a [paramecium](https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/icon-of-paramecium-caudatum-specie-of-unicellular-vector-18985657) like object travel around the perimeter of the organism similar to the treads on a tank.

I've managed to have the objects trace the perimeter of this shape, but my hope was to have this shape pulse while keeping the objects snapped to the perimeter. When I try to animate the guide layer itself I'm required to convert it to a symbol which seems to remove its guide properties.

Is there any way to animate the guide while keeping any child layers locked to its path?

For reference, here's the tutorial I was able to successfully follow for the initial animation along the guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZRmJGKPVro